# How to restrict withdrawal in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

When user sign up he get free amount of 100, amount is present in the "USERS" table. I want that a user cannot withdraw (amount in "Withdraw" table), if he has no record in the "Fund" table.

I tried the following in the withdraw controller. If the "Fund" table holds a record, it will return the view, otherwise it will redirect to login.

Is this right?

```
 public function newWithdraw()
 {
      $fund = Fund::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();

      if ($fund==null)
      {
           Session::flash('type','danger');
           Session::flash('message','please add funds atleast once');
           return redirect()->route('login');
      }
      else
          $data['general'] = GeneralSetting::first();

      $data['site_title'] = $data['general']->title;
      $data['basic'] = BasicSetting::first();
      $data['page_title'] = "User Withdraw Method";
      $data['method'] = ManualPayment::whereStatus(1)->get();
      return view('withdraw.withdraw-new',$data);
  }
```

Comment: Please check, if you posted really your original code. Is there a `{` missing after else?

Answer (score 0):

Use `empty()` to check `Fund` have a record or not.

```
public function noamount()
{
    $fund = Fund::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();

    if (empty($fund)) {
       return redirect()->back()->with('type','danger')->with('message','please add funds atleast once');
    }
}
```

Comment: Your logic is wrong, `$fund` is a record with many fields, one of those fields is amount and the OP wants to check that amount in funds

Comment: @SapneshNaik he says no records in fund table

Comment: You are right. The OP needs to clarify more on this

Comment: how should  set setup code in blade according to this

Comment: check session that type and message exists, if exists then show

Comment: @Sohel0415  i am  going t update logic in question please check it

Comment: your logic is completely wrong, fund should not be related with session, its only related with withdrawn, so you should redirect with a error or redirect to a different page, i am updating my answer, you can do like that